# Visual Studio 2017 with missing pane for changing design code view option

Tags: .net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRukR.png)The code view / design view option is not available. I have reset all windows, gone in the tool options and set to split. i have went through all the view options and checked unchecked to try and get the pane to show up. can someone point me in the right direction. i have been reading and messing with this for 2 days now. I don't have enough credit to post a picture of it but maybe someone can help. The answered questions related to this isn't the same.

I have tried resetting, reinstalling, reading, changing, installing again. i cant find this window pane option to change from design code view. nothing is minimized and nothing is hidden. it just isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently starting a new web application it's there. Not sure why or what that has to do with it.